java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (StatefulPartitionedCall:0) with 420 bytes to a Java Buffer with 28 bytes
I'm currently attempting to add my YOLOv7 custom trained model into an Android app. I've followed the steps outlined in Converting YOLOv7 to Tensorflow Lite to convert the .pt weights file into a .tflite model.
I've followed various YouTube tutorials on adding the .tflite file into Android Studio however, I keep running into the same error (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (StatefulPartitionedCall:0) with 420 bytes to a Java Buffer with 28 bytes) when running the model.process command. I'm not sure how to debug this issue and I've checked that both the TensorBuffer and ByteBuffer shapes are the same. Here is the code:
Yolov7ModelInt16 model = Yolov7ModelInt16.newInstance(MainActivity.this);

                    // Creates inputs for reference.
                    TensorBuffer inputFeature0 = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(new int[]{1, 3, 640, 640}, DataType.FLOAT32);
                    bitmap=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,640,640,false);
                    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1*3*640*640*4);
                    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

                    int[] intValues = new int[640 * 640];
                    bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, 640, 0, 0, 640, 640);

                    int pixel = 0;
                    for (int y = 0; y < 640; y++) {
                        for (int x = 0; x < 640; x++) {
                            int pixelValue = intValues[pixel++];
                            byteBuffer.putFloat(Color.red(pixelValue) / 255.0f);
                            byteBuffer.putFloat(Color.green(pixelValue) / 255.0f);
                            byteBuffer.putFloat(Color.blue(pixelValue) / 255.0f);
                        }
                    }

                    inputFeature0.loadBuffer(byteBuffer);

                    Yolov7ModelInt16.Outputs outputs = model.process(inputFeature0);
                    TensorBuffer outputFeature0 = outputs.getOutputFeature0AsTensorBuffer();

                    result.setText(labels[getMax(outputFeature0.getFloatArray())]+"");

                    // Releases model resources if no longer used.
                    model.close();

I've had a look the input and output of the model on Netron (shown below), but I am unable to resolve the issue. The only thing I can only deduce from the error message is that the model output does not match the ByteBuffer input. I tried to change the datatype of the TensorBuffer input (to UINT8) and adjust the ByteBuffer size accordingly (divide by 4), but to no avail.
Netron input/output
Would greatly appreciate any guidance.
Thanks!
